# redis hscan command cannot limit the counts

Tags: redis

my redis version:3.0.2
Hash data as below show.
key name:test
contents(values):
1) "xx1"
2) "1"
3) "xx2"
4) "2"
5) "xx3"
6) "3"
7) "xx4"
8) "4"
9) "xx5"
10)"5"
use commond -->HSCAN test 0 COUNT 2
Redis return every key and value, not the first of 2 keys and values!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

COUNT option for SCAN does not limit the number of key-values returned.

It is used to force the command to increase the number key-values returned.

Redis COUNT option [doc](http://redis.io/commands/scan#the-count-option):

> - When iterating Sets encoded as intsets (small sets composed of just
>     integers), or Hashes and Sorted Sets encoded as ziplists (small hashes
>     and sets composed of small individual values), usually all the
>     elements are returned in the first SCAN call regardless of the COUNT
>     value.

So, get first two values from the result of `HSCAN test 0` command.

Comment: Great!i see, when i put a large number of data into my hash set,the COUNT opthion worked!Thanks!

Comment: Even for large number of data COUNT will not always get you the accurate number of results. It can be equal or more than the COUNT.